# Does Aqua wear panties?

Tags: konosuba

[image]

The goddess Aqua, who meets Kazuma after his terrible death.
The question is, does Aqua wear panties?

If there is, G-strings, the very tight ones? Is there any mentions about these in the novel?

Comment: Most likely a case of [Schrödinger's panties](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s%20panties) or the fact that there are 2 different shades of purple could indicate that the lighter shade is her undergarment (as it's shape does not match the skirt unlike the darker purple)

Comment: This question made my day. @Memor-X not sure that's any sort of undergarment, more like a thing short dress that would go over undergarments--not sure of the name.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, Aqua does wear panties.

In the first volume of the light novel her panties are shown, in all of their striped glory.

> [image: Aquas panties]